# web2py db import issue

Tags: web2py, pythonanywhere

having an issue with web2py on pythonanywhere.
I am reading a text file and spliting it and putting the values into a list, have also tried list of tuples.
The data is clearly there but wont let me put it in, keeps saying it is null when i know the list is populated.

Error:
 artist3.numT may not be NULL

```
dbcode
# coding: utf8
fp = open('/home/dingadestroy/count.txt','r')
ft1 = fp.read()
li = []
artists = []
tweets = []
classArt = []
text = []
count = []
def getCount():
    count = []
    x = ft1.split('\n')
    for i in x:
        z = i.split('\t')
        if len(z)>=2:
            artists.append(z[0])
            li.append(z[1])

getCount()

db.define_table('artist3',
                Field('name','text'),
                Field('numT','text',notnull=True))

#db.define_table('artist',
     #           Field('name',notnull=True,unique=True),
       #         format = '%(name)s')


for th in li:
    for ar in artists:
            db.artist3.insert(name=ar)
            db.artist3.insert(numT=int(th))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
db.artist3.insert(name=ar)
```

You are creating a new *artist3* with a name, and without *numT* (numT=NULL)

When you do

```
db.artist3.insert(numT=int(th))
```

You are creating a new *artist3* without name (name=NULL), and with a *numT*

According to your table definition, you doesn't want a NULL numT `Field('numT','text',notnull=True)`

So you should probably replace these two insert

```
db.artist3.insert(name=ar)
db.artist3.insert(numT=int(th))
```

with a single insert

```
db.artist3.insert(name=ar, numT=int(th))
```